# Can do it sd a sdc?

Tags: ios

I have the following code:

```
publi       his);
    return ;
}
```

sad
How should I start rewriting my code?

Comment: Probably, you haven't included most of the relevant information though

Comment: i didnt understand what you want to achive but you can always manually iterate result of child.InOrder() and add items one by one

Comment: Hard to say, especially since I don't know what `child.InOrder()` does, but I think something like `Children.SelectMany(c => c)` is what you want.

Comment: I think you can list.AddRange(Children); with no foreach loop or in the loop list.Add(child);

Answer (score 4):

A good way to implement the traversal without `AddRange` is to simply use an iterator block instead:

```
public IEnumerable<Node<T>> PostOrder()
{
    List<Node<T>> list = new List<Node<T>>();
    if (Children != null)
    {                
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            foreach (var node in child.PostOrder()) {
                yield return node;
            }
        }                
    }

    yield return this;
}
```

This way of doing things means that you do not *have* to allocate a list containing all the nodes; you can simply `foreach` over the results. If for some reason you do want a list, then that is also trivial to get:

```
var list = node.PostOrder().ToList();
```